# Running a PDO mysql_num_rows query

Tags: mysql, pdo, mysql-num-rows

How do I run this as a PDO query?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `Top_10` WHERE DOB =". $date;
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0){
while blah blah
}
```

I can run the PDO fetch array. But as soon as I do this, it fails.

Any ideas?

Comment: Too bad you don't show the equivalent PDO based code and tell us how it fails.  Moreover `"SELECT * FROM ``Top_10`` WHERE DOB =". $date` is both horribly inefficient and SQL injection prone.  The performance concern can be addressed by doing `"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ``Top_10`` WHERE DOB = ..."`

Answer (score 0):

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$dbname", $user, $password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);

try {
  $qry = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM Top_10 WHERE DOB = ?');
  $qry->execute([$date]);

  while ($row = $qry->fetch()) {
    // blah blah blah
  }
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
  die($e->getMessage());
}
```